# Create list of files in Azure Storage and send it to sql table using ADF

Tags: azure, dataset, blob, azure-data-factory

I need to copy file names of excel files that are in my Azure Storage as blobs and then put these names in the SQL Server table using ADF. It can be a file path as a name of a file but the hardest thing is that in the dataset which takes all the files from one specific folder I have to select a sheet name and these sheet names are different for each file, therefore it returns an error. Is there a way to create a collective dataset without indicating the sheet name?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question correctly you are looking for a way to write all Excel filenames to a SQL Database using ADF.

You can use the generic Get Metadata activity and use a binary dataset as source. Select Child items as an field to retrieve. This will retrieve all files in the folder. Then add a filter to only select the Excel file types.

[image: Get Metadata]

Hope that this gets you on the right track.